# algorithm to find out all the locations within a range

Tags: java, performance, graph, graph-algorithm, graph-databases

I need to process a very large road network graph containing say more than 10,000 nodes. Suppose I have a source node 'S' in the graph which represents a place or a particular location having a specific longitude and latitude. Now my application requires to find out all the places which are existing within 5 km region in the real world around the location represented by 'S' in the graph. Suppose my graph is very dense and hundreds of nodes representing various places/locations may be there in the graph within this 5 km region as mentioned.

### The nodes represent locations and the edge weights represent distance between two neighbor nodes whose range is from 100 meters to 100 kilometers. So my questions are -

1) How to find out all the nodes efficiently so that less memory and runtime is used? Any special data structure or algorithm to use?

2) If I use neo4j graph database in Java application then how to solve the problem? code segment, cypher query for neo4j + proper theory would be appreciated.

*Please provide a solution considering a large scale network.

Edit: In my application it is quite possible that a node is processed again and again i.e; suppose in an instance desired nodes for the source node 'S' are found and later in another instance the same process is to be performed for another node 'S1' which is adjacent to 'S'. So it may happen that the nodes which were processed for the case of 'S', most of them are again processed/traversed for 'S1' as 'S' and 'S1' are adjacent. So is there any way of caching the results so that nodes are not processed again and again? Any efficient algorithm rather that Dijkastra or BFS? In BFS even any caching possible?

Comment: *Please provide an attempted solution to your own problem so we can help you instead of do it for you.

Comment: well code or query for neo4j was asked not the full code.

Comment: You still didn't provide any neo4j code.  We don't just write code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Both if you use Neo4j or some other way of representing the graph, you should probably do a BFS (breadth-first search) from the source node `S`.

In Neo4j, you can use a [Traversal](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorial-traversal-java-api.html) that already implements a BFS.

You will get a better answer from someone if you put more effort into your question. It's nearly impossible to give you a better answer without doing all the work for you now.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Dejsktras algorithm modification, which uses O(n) operations in the worst case

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)

> 1. Assign to every node a tentative distance value: set it to zero for our initial node and to infinity for all other nodes.
> 2. Mark all nodes unvisited. Set the initial node as current. Create a set of the unvisited nodes called the unvisited set consisting of all
>      the nodes.
> 3. For the current node, consider all of its unvisited neighbors and calculate their tentative distances. Compare the newly calculated
>      tentative distance to the current assigned value and assign the
>      smaller one. For example, if the current node A is marked with a
>      distance of 6, and the edge connecting it with a neighbor B has length
>      2, then the distance to B (through A) will be 6 + 2 = 8. If B was
>      previously marked with a distance greater than 8 then change it for 8.
>      Otherwise, keep the current value.
> 4. When we are done considering all of the neighbors of the current node, mark the current node as visited and remove it from the
>      unvisited set. A visited node will never be checked again.
> 5. If the destination node has been marked visited (when planning a route between two specific nodes) or if the smallest tentative
>      distance among the nodes in the unvisited set is infinity (when
>      planning a complete traversal; occurs when there is no connection
>      between the initial node and remaining unvisited nodes), then stop.
>      The algorithm has finished.
> 6. Select the unvisited node that is marked with the smallest tentative distance, and set it as the new "current node" then go back
>      to step 3.

Do the following modification:

> In the 6th point, if the distance is more than a given range stop the
>   algorithm, and all market nodes that has a mark less or equal to given
>   range are nodes you are looking for

(Note: not clear from question... I assume, that you have a graph, each edge of which have a distance between two neighbor nodes... )